# getting the text up-side down in core graphic

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, drawrect

I am drawing a text in core graphic by following

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 20, 150);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, 1);

    // Draw the text using the MyDrawText function
    myDrawText(context, viewBounds);

}
void myDrawText (CGContextRef myContext, CGRect contextRect) 
{
    CGFloat w, h;
    w = contextRect.size.width;
    h = contextRect.size.height;

    CGAffineTransform myTextTransform;
    CGContextSelectFont (myContext, 
                         "Helvetica-Bold",
                         h/12,
                         kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (myContext, .5); 
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (myContext, kCGTextFill); 

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 1, 1, 1, 1); 
    myTextTransform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation  (0); 
    CGContextSetTextMatrix (myContext, myTextTransform); 
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint (myContext, 115, 0, "Successful", 10); 
}
```

After running it I am getting the text is in up-side down like below
[image]

Why the text is up side down after the drawing

Please advice me on this issue.

Comment: did the answer below helped you? If it did, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the way to flip it. Just add 2 lines to your drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 20, 150);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, 1);
CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);

// Draw the text using the MyDrawText function
myDrawText(context, self.bounds);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CGContextSetTextMatrix (myContext, myTextTransform);`

You need to change this line so that instead of being identity, you scale it -1 vertically and offset it vertically by its height.

EDIT:  Sorry, not that line, you need to flip the graphics context, and simply change that line to be CGAffineTransformIdentity.  Any tutorial on Core Text will have the lines you need to draw text the right way.

Comment: can you tell me more detail about it. I am so new about these stuff.

Comment: Well, what do you know about translation, rotation and scaling?